# Variational representation of matrix operator norm

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, svd

Let $W \in \mathbb R^{n\times d}$ and $\mathbb M = \{\Theta \in \mathbb R^{n\times d} | \text{rank}(\Theta)=1, \|\Theta\|_F = 1\}$ where $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the frobenius norm. Show that the operator norm has the following variational representation:

$$\|W\|_2 = \sup_{\Theta \in \mathbb M} \langle W, \Theta \rangle$$

My guess is that we can write the SVD of $W$ then apply properties of trace and the matrices of left and right singular vectors to show that the supremum is equivalent to pulling out the max singular value.

Comment: That's a good guess. Did you try it?

Comment: $\sup \langle W, \Theta\rangle = \sup \langle U \Sigma V^T, \Theta\rangle = \sup \langle \Sigma, V\Theta U^T\rangle$ But since $V, U$ are orthogonal, they are rotations, so that $ = \sup \langle \Sigma, \Theta\rangle$ which is obviously just the maximum singular value.

Comment: Ok i suppose it's time to read your blog post on svd

Comment: Yes, that'll work, although you should say a little more about that last step.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints: If $\operatorname{rk} \Theta =1$ then it can be written as $\Theta = uv^T$. Show that $\|\Theta\|_F = \|u\|_2 \|v\|_2$. Note that
$\langle W, uv^T \rangle_F = u^T Wv$.